# Math formula editor with export to SVG, EPS or AI

Tags: software-rec, equation-editor

I'm looking for a free formula editor, which can export formulas to vector-based formats. (SVG, EPS, AI, PDF, CDR, etc..)

Do you know of any such program?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an [Online LaTeX Equation Editor](http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php) which can output in svg format. There also some TeX programs for different platforms you can download from [CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/). This list contains all the great [EPS Editors](https://www.techwhoop.com/eps-editor-software/) as of 2018.

Answer (score 1):

There is also another free online equation editor at [formulasheet.com](http://formulasheet.com/editor.php) that can export in .pdf format. It is a bit more user friendly and powerful than the codecogs one.